# Changing values of items in an array using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, equality, indexof

```
var num = [ 5 ];
var row = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
row[4] = num
alert (num.indexOf(row[4])); /* alerts: -1 */
alert (num.indexOf(row[0])); /* alerts: -1 */
alert (row[4]);              /* alerts:  5 */
alert (row);                 /* alerts: 0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 5 */
```

I don't understand why the first two alerts return "**-1**" instead of, respectively, "**5**" and "**0**", do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

**line1:**

```
row[4] = num
```

**line2:**

```
alert (num.indexOf(row[4])); /* alerts: -1 */
```

**line3:**

```
alert (num.indexOf(row[0])); /* alerts: -1 */
```

after line 1 is executed

`row[4] = [5]` and not 5 as you may think therefore **indexOf** returns -1

now, for the second part:

`num` is still `[5]`, so what is the index of **row[0]** or what is the index of 0 in that variable?? well -1 too (since that value is not present in that array)

Answer (score 1):

`row[4] = 4`
`num` does not contain value `4` thus `-1` is returned (-1 means no such item in an array)

same goes to `num.indexOf(row[0])`

`arrayToLookThru.indexOf(valueToLookFor)` - this is how it works.

`indexOf` returns position of the **first** element with a given value and `-1` if no elemets found.